Nginx reverse proxy : read non-HTTP headers
I am using nginx as a reverse proxy to have all my services on port 443.
I have various services such as :

web : about 6 websites/admin panels
SSH
SFTP
WireGuard
and maybe others in the future...

I am using the following config to separate web traffic and other traffic :
stream {

        upstream ssh {
                server localhost:<sshPort>;
        }

        upstream sftp {
                server localhost:<sftpPort>;
        }

        upstream vpn {
                server localhost:<WGPort>;
        }

        upstream web {
                server localhost:<X>;
        }

        map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
                "" ssh;
                default web;
                "TLSv1.3" web;
                "TLSv1.2" web;
                "TLSv1.1" web;
                "TLSv1" web;
        }

        server {
                listen 443;
                listen 80;
                ssl_preread on;
                proxy_pass $upstream;
        }

}

That X is the port where a second nginx config is running to split web traffic according to subdomain.
The problem is that I can only enable one non-TLS service at a time, and if I want to change, I have to manually edit the config and reload Nginx.
So here's my question : is there an nginx command/plugin/alternative that can read SSH and WireGuard headers and separate them ?
I need some kind of non-HTTP multiplexer.
Thanks !

Take a look at sslh or something like that. I don't think than nginx is a good choice for this task.

@AlexeyTen ok thanks, I'll have a look
